# Dimensionality of GMM Estimation

Tags: matrix, generalized-moments

So in my class today we discussed GMM estimation and how we can derive OLS using GMM. I am struggling with the matrix algebra with GMM (from Summations to Matricies)

$$g(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i,\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{x}_i'(y_i-\textbf{x}_i'\beta)=\frac{1}{n}\textbf{X}'(\textbf{y}-\textbf{X}\beta)$$

How did we get this for example...

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{x}_i'y_i=\frac{1}{n}\textbf{X}'\textbf{y}$$

and this for example

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{x}_i'\textbf{x}_i\beta=\frac{1}{n}\textbf{X}'\beta$$

from the summation into Matrix from

Because I though

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{x}_i\textbf{x}_i'=\textbf{X}$$

Comment: This will help you:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198257/intuition-for-the-product-of-vector-and-matrices-xtax/198280#198280

Answer (score 0):

When you write $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{y}$, basically you are multiplying each row of $\mathbf{X}$ with the column vector $\mathbf{y}$. 
To understand this, take a $2 \times 2$ matrix as an example and multiply with a column vector.

Comment: The OP seemed to be having more issues with the multiplication by 1/n than the linear algebra. Perhaps you could expand this to deal with all his/her confusions?